# Discard a card to gain money

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

Which cards am I allowed to discard in order to gain money in *Seven Wonders Duel*?

1. A card I already acquired and placed in my home?
2. A free unclaimed card from the board (a card a player could otherwise get paying its costs)?

In other words, discarding is an alternative to get a card from the table on one player's turn?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, thats incorrect, you can not chose to avoid taking a card from the structure and discarding a card from your board for money.

The rules state under Game Turn :-

> "On your turn, you must choose an “accessible” card in
>   the card structure and play it. An accessible card is a card which
>   isn’t partially covered by other cards."

Note it says the structure, not anything in your play area.  'Structure' being the term for how cards are laid out each age. You then have a choice with the card you selected to build it, discard it for money, or construct a wonder.

So to answer your question, the only card you may discard for money is the one you took from the structure that turn and no other.  You do not pay any costs associated with building a card if you are just taking it to discard for money.