# 7 Wonders Duel no one can pick a card due to lack of resource

Tags: 7-wonders-duel

What happens if neither player can pick up one of the laid cards due to a lack of resources? Is there some kind of order based on which they must be placed because the rules of the game do not say this?

Comment: This is not quite a duplicate question but might be a similar misunderstanding of the rules.  This question was from a player who thought discarding a card for money was one that they had built rather one they built.
 https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/28396/discard-a-card-to-gain-money?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

On your turn, you always have three choices:

1. Construct the Building
2. Discard the card to obtain coins
3. Construct a Wonder

If you don't have the resources to actually construct the building or put it towards a Wonder, you can always discard it for 2 coins plus one coin for every yellow card in your city.